# What are the dependencies for django-allauth python:3.8.3-alpine Dockerfile

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, dockerfile, django-allauth

I have a Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, requirements.txt defined below for a django project. The Dockerfile uses **python:3.8.3-alpine** and the docker-compose.yml have a db service that uses **postgres:12.0-alpine image**. I made sure that the dependencies are defined in the Dockerfile as required. However, it seems to me that django-allauth require extra dependencies. I have tried for days to fix this issue but get an error that says
**This package requires Rust >=1.41.0.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography**. I haved pasted the whole error for reference sake. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#requirements.txt
Django>=3.1.5,<3.2.0
gunicorn>=20.0.4,<20.1.0
psycopg2-binary>=2.8,<2.9
Pillow>=8.1.0,<8.2.0
django-allauth>=0.44.0,<1.0.0
```

```
#Dockerfile
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add libffi-dev libressl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg 
    

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .

# copy project
COPY . .

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django_dev

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

```
#The error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpqrozof2e
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_969ve76/cryptography_7b36a9983e174247ad8f5924b01b6bcc
  Complete output (163 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/ocsp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/certificate_transparency.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/_types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/_der.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/_oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_asymmetric.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/poly1305.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_cipheralgorithm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x448.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed448.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/ssh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/pkcs12.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/pkcs7.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/aead.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ocsp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ed25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/aead.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/poly1305.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x448.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ed448.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  running egg_info
  writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.github'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'mypy.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.d'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.playbooks'
  writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying src/cryptography/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
  
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_padding.c'
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_openssl.c'
  running build_rust
  
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install cryptography:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
         instructions for your platform.
      3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
      4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
      5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
         set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
  
  error: can't find Rust compiler
  
  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.
  
  To update pip, run:
  
      pip install --upgrade pip
  
  and then retry package installation.
  
  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
  
  This package requires Rust >=1.41.0.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python:3.8.2-alpine
adding `cryptography==3.1.1 in requirements`
In Dockerfile

```
CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST 1
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo
```

This works for me, but be ready for your docker image will be +300~500 MB

Answer (score 1):

`django-allauth` requires `cryptography` which [now requires Rust to compile](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/main/docs/installation.rst). You could try updating your Dockerfile with the newer python release, i.e. `FROM python:3.8.8-alpine`, which might let it fetch the prebuilt binary for cryptography.

If that doesn't work you need to add the Rust dependencies so it can compile the package.

```
# install dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add libffi-dev libressl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg \
    && apk add rust cargo # ADDED LINE
```